# PHP: go back to the start of loop using a sort of 'break'?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Hi i have a loop and i was wondering if there was a command that you can jump back to the start of the loop and ignore the rest of the code in the loop

example:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < 10; $index++) 
{
    if ($index == 6)
        that command to go the start of the loop

    echo "$index, ";
}
```

should output

1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9
and skip the six

sort of same result as

```
for ($index = 0; $index < 10; $index++) 
{
    if ($index != 6)
        echo "$index, ";
}
```

is there a command for that?

thanks,
matthy

Comment: `continue`: the PHP manual is your friend.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The keyword to use is `continue`:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < 10; $index++) 
{
    if ($index == 6)
        continue; // Skips everything below it and jumps to next iteration

    echo "$index, ";
}
```

As an aside, to get your desired output your `for` line should read this instead (unless you missed zero):

```
for ($index = 1; $index < 10; $index++)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `continue` advances to the next iteration.